# Editing .xsl files UnicodeEncodeError with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am writing a function that reads xml and xml like files (.xsl, .resx, .dtd, .mcr, .xpr, .svg, .tbr, .user, .settings, etc.), removes their comments using bs4, and rewrites the file.

```
import sys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment

def remove_xml_style_comments(filename):
    soup = BS(open(filename),"lxml")
    comments=soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

    for c in comments:
        c.extract()
    new_file = open(filename,"w")
    new_file.write(str(soup.prettify()))
    new_file.close()
```

I have tested this function on thousands of test files. It seems to work perfectly fine for all the above file types except for certain .xsl files. About 2-3% out of the 182 .xsl files tested returned the error:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 7558: character maps to <undefined>
```

when I tried to read them in.

My question is: How can i properly read in these files so that I can avoid this error for these specific .xsl files?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes need to be made.

First, read the file in as binary:

```
soup = BS(open(filename, 'rb'),"lxml")
```

Second, encode using utf-8 when opening the new file to be written to:

```
new_file = open(filename,'w', encoding="utf-8")
```